# Reciprocal Zeta function: between 0 and 1/2?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, meromorphic-functions

According to resources from the internet, if Riemann Hypothesis is true, then 
$$\frac1{\zeta (z)}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\mu (n)}{n^z}$$ converges for $1/2<\sigma$.

However, I cannot find any continuation of it for $0\le \sigma <1/2$.

($\sigma$ is the real part of the argument $z$)

Does the continuation require assuming RH to be true?

I believe such continuation exists, as meromorphic continuation is often possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\sigma$ here ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with “provide”? The $\zeta$ function is meromorphic and therefore if $Z=\{\text{zeros of }\zeta\}$, then $\frac1\zeta\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus(Z\cup\{1\})\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is a meromorphic function (which can be extended to $\mathbb{C}\setminus Z$ as a meromorphic function). So, yes, it has a continuation. This doesn't depend upon the Riemann hyphotesis.

Comment: Then what is the continued function? Is it the same as the one provided in the question?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^z}$ doesn't converge if $\operatorname{Re}z<\frac12$.

Comment: Do you know the series valid for $\sigma <1/2$?

Comment: @Szeto The series diverges when $\sigma<\frac12$.

Comment: So do you mean no series is avaliable for $\sigma < 1/2$?

Comment: @Szeto No, I did not mean that. But, in fact, no Dirichlet series converges to $\frac1\zeta in that region.

Comment: Thank you. However, I’m interested that, as far as you know, what is the most beautiful/simple series representation of $1/\zeta (z)$ in that region?

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos You write "no Dirichlet series converges to $\frac{1}{\zeta}$ in that region" with the region being the left hand side of the critical strip, namely $0<\Re s<1/2$ under RH. Do you happen to have a reference for this statement please?

Comment: I am just using the fact that there are zeros on the critical line and that therefore $\frac1\zeta$ is undefined at those points. So, no Dirichlet seres can converge to $\frac1\zeta$ in that region, since that would mean that it would converge at every point of the region.

Answer (score 0):

The reciprocal of the zeta function *is* the analytic continuation of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\mu(n)\over n^z}$. This series clearly converges absolutely when $\sigma=\Re(z)\gt1$ (as does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^z}$ for the zeta function itself). What the Riemann Hypothesis implies (indeed, is equivalent to) is that it converges *conditionally* when $\sigma\gt1/2$.

Comment: So is there a series of $1/\zeta (z)$ that is suitable for $\sigma <1/2$? If yes, what is it?